# MVC3 Ajax.BeginForm doesn't show ValidationMessage

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using MVC3 + Razor. Now I have a form which contains Ajax.BeginForm(...). I following exact what "Maxim" said in this post:

[ASP.NET MVC AJAX with HTML.ValidationMessageFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388700/asp-net-mvc-ajax-with-html-validationmessagefor)

And my validation rule is defined like:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ControlName", "error message");
```

However my

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.OneProperty[0].AnotherProperty)
```

didn't give me anything.

I also put these code into partial-view for "error summary" as well. I could see code run through the "ValidationSummary" PV, but it just doesn't display.

```
 if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
 {
    <div id="errorMessage" class="notificationArea">
             @Html.Partial("ValidationSummary")
    </div>
  }
```

---

In short, my main view is this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveFromMainView", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "myForm"   
}, 
    new { id = "myForm" }))
{           

    @Html.Partial("SamTest1")
}
```

And within this "SamTest1" partial-view, there is another "ValidationSummary" partial-view to display bullets of error message.

And my action method fianlly:

```
return PartialView("SamTest1");
```

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using Html.ValidationSummary?  Also, make sure that you have enabled clientvalidation and added in the unobtrusive libraries.  Finally, any valiationmessages will only display if the control name you add to the modelstate matches the name of one of the validationmessagefor controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  got it work. Actually it's due to incorrect bind of model. I have a list of model object, and had though something like ControlFor(model => Model[0].PropertyName) ... would work. Actually it's not.

After changing it to normal model binding, the validation message shows now.

Thanks again all!